# How can extract the filename from the below JSON data

Tags: json, jq

I am new to `jq` and not sure how to go about extracting just the filenames from the below JSON file.

```
{
  "files" : [ {
    "name" : "filename1.gz",
    "StartDate" : "2018-07-09T11:00:00-04:00",
    "EndDate" : "2018-07-09T12:00:00-04:00"
  }, {
    "name" : "filename2.gz",
    "StartDate" : "2018-07-09T10:00:00-04:00",
    "EndDate" : "2018-07-09T11:00:00-04:00"
  }, {
    "name" : "filename3.gz",
    "StartDate" : "2018-07-09T09:00:00-04:00",
    "EndDate" : "2018-07-09T10:00:00-04:00"
 }, {
    "name" : "filename4.gz",
    "StartDate" : "2018-07-09T07:00:00-04:00",
    "EndDate" : "2018-07-09T08:00:00-04:00"
  } ]
}
```

expected output:

```
[filename1.gz,filename2.gz,filename3.gz,filename4.gz]
```

Comment: `jq '[.files | .[] | .name]'`?

Comment: `jq --indent 0 '[.files | .[] | .name]'` if you don't want the default indentation.

Comment: Are you really sure you want the output without quotes `".."`?

Answer (score 1):

I see @Abdou has already given solution to this, just adding in another minified version to achieve the desired solution.

> jq --compact-output '[.files[].name]'